# Cart Slideup on mouse hover and slide down on mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, slideshow, show-hide

I have implemented a shopping cart , which requires a cart details to be shown on top when product is added in Cart .

[Link](http://hurom.php-dev.in/)

In header part there is cart symbol which after on adding products show cart details .

Till now have added code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
            jQuery('.block-cart-custom').mouseover(function() {
                jQuery('#cart_header_content').slideDown(500);
            });
            jQuery('.block-cart-custom').mouseleave(function() {
                jQuery('#cart_header_content').hide(500);
            });
       });
        </script>
```

Please tell where I am getting wrong .

One can add product in cart and check the same --- > [Link](http://hurom.php-dev.in/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a combination of `mouseover` and `mouseout` OR `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.  Right now you are using `mouseover` and `mouseleave` which might be causing your problem. A simpler option would be to use `hover`.

Here is your code with `hover` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.block-cart-custom').hover(function(){
        $('#cart_header_content').slideDown(500);
    },function(){
        $('#cart_header_content').hide(500);
        //you could alternatively use slideUp instead of hide
    }
});
```

Documentation:

[mouseover api](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

[hover api](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)